# My custom WP plugin not showing in customizer

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my first Wordpress Plugin I'm developing so please forgive if I am asking the obvious. Also using Wordpress v4.7

I created a file animate-css.php and added it to the plugins folder of my locally hosted site. I logged in and activated the plugin, but for some reason the section is not showing despite I followed the docs, https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin .

Code:

```
<?php 

/*
Plugin Name: Animate-css 
Plugin URI: http://noneasyet.sorry
Description: Enter the animate class you would like to add to any DOM element.
Version: 1.0
Author: Shannon Williams
Author URI:  http://stillnoneyet.againsorry
*/

function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
//All our sections, settings, and controls will be added here

$wp_customize->add_section( 'Animate Elements' , array(
'title'      => __( 'Animate Elements' ),
'priority'   => 10,
 ));
}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );

?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Aha!

Firstly, this is the wrong section on StackExchange to post a question for Wordpress. Secondly, the correct sections and answer is [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/228365/add-action-customize-register-not-working).

You always need to define the section,control and setting. The link above explains it more in detail.